# How to get a property from other class in CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to get a property to a class from another class.

Here's my simple test HTML:

```
<div class='test bgcolor'> An arrow! </div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.test{
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.bgcolor{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.test:after{
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-right-color: yellow;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Class `bgcolor` sets a background color and it can be changed from yellow to another color in a typical situation.

And `test:after` is for the small arrow and arrow color should be same as of a box which is determined by background-color attribute in a class `bgcolor`.

Now, I got a problem that how can I set border-right-color in 'test:after' with the value of background-color in `bgcolor`.

If this problem could be solved, the only thing I need to change the color of (arrow + box) is just changing the color in `bgcolor`.

Please give me an advice.

Thank you.

Comment: [CSS doesn't have anything called 'a class'](http://pumpula.net/p/apps/css-vocabulary/). You appear to be looking for the term "rule-set".

Comment: @Quentin I have not known about that term but I use 'class' because it is in HTML tag, <div class='test bgcolor'>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are CSS Variables. They would make something like this possible:

```
--testBGColor: yellow;

.bgcolor {
    background-color:var(--testBGColor);
}

.test:after {
    border-right-color:var(--testBGColor);
    ...
}
```

The problem with this approach is that CSS variables aren't supported by the major browsers yet: [Can I use CSS variables?](http://caniuse.com/css-variables)

So you'll have to use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

A solution with LESS:

```
@testBGColor: yellow;

.bgcolor {
    background-color:@testBGColor;
}

.test:after {
    border-right-color:@testBGColor;
    ...
}
```

But remember that LESS is a preprocessor meaning the above code will be compiled into pure CSS either during runtime or after coding. It's not part of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this just works?

```
 }
 .bgcolor{
     background-color: yellow;
     border-color: yellow;
     border-width: 0;
 }
 .test:after{
     right: 100%;
     top: 50%;
     border: solid transparent;
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     border-width: 10px;
     margin-top: -10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/) declaring a variable and using it in your classes.

```
$yellow: #FFC900;

.bgColor { background-color: $yellow; }

.test:after { 
    border-right-color: $yellow;
    ...
}
```

That's a Sass example.

Answer (score 0):

Add to div, one more class like ".theme-1" for first color and customize it

```
.bgcolor.theme-1{
    background-color: red;
    border-color: red;
}

.bgcolor.theme-1:after{
    border-right-color: red;
}
```

and so on with ".theme-2",".theme-3" etc